# PHP with sqlsrv update / insert glitch writing zeros

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I don't really know where to start with this one, and don't really even know if this is a valid question, but here it goes.

I have a PHP application that connects to SQL Server 2008 R2 using the sqlsrv driver. Everything works great without issues 99.9% of the time.

The issue that I am facing is that very rarely, on an insert or update statement, the application will write all zeros to every field for a record instead of writing the actual values.

I have checked the error logs (IIS, PHP, SQL Server) and have found absolutely nothing of relevance.

I don't even know how to debug this as everything works 99.9% of the time. Has anyone else ever encountered something like this?

Comment: By any chance is SQL Server restarting when the zeros are written?

Comment: There is not, the only time SQL server gets restarted on this server is when we schedule down time.